# cannot repeat animation  - jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I can't repeat animation with the following example (using [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/))

```
$("#rotateDiv2").button().click(function() {
    $('#second').transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        easing: 'snap',
        duration: '3000ms',
        rotate3d: '1, 1, 0, 360deg'
    });
});
```

It does work, only it work once (when clicking the button of course). the second time i click its doing nothing. Thanx!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the CSS transform property in the callback:

http://jsfiddle.net/zA2ZQ/2/

```
$("#rotateDiv2").button().click(function() {
    $('#second').transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        easing: 'snap',
        duration: '3000ms',
        rotate3d: '1, 1, 0, 360deg'
    }, function(){
      //reset the transform property
      $(this).css('transform', '');
    });
});​
```

Comment: it works, only it resets the attributes and its a bit of a problem cause the div is draggble and resizable ,after the reset, it returns to start point. if no other workaround, should i keep last attributes > reset > restore attr ? how can this be done?

Comment: just resetting the transform property seems to do it (updated the answer)