# jquery transition stop and go on demand

Tags: jquery, transition

I am trying to use transition to stop and replay on demands .
however I found that I can't fully  clear the first transition by useing clearQueue();

this is my testing script
I try to stop the first animation (which is set to run 10 sec) at t=7000 and replace it 
with a 4 sec run backward

```
$("#item").transition({"left":1200},10000,'linear'); // first animation
setTimeout(function(){
    tte=$("#item").css("left");
    $("#item").css("left",tte);
    $("#item").clearQueue();
    $("#item").transition({"left":100},4000,'linear'); //second animation
},7000); //stop the first on t=7000
```

I can start the second one with clearQueue()..however the transition jump to end at t=10000 
(it should stop at 7000+4000=11000)

if not use clearQueue() ..it will stop at 7000 and wait another 3000 then start the second one..

anyway I can make this to work?
(this can be done with .animate(),but I need this to run on tablet and phone ..)
thank you to your advice...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579287/cannot-repeat-animation-jquery

Comment: .css('transform', '')...is not working...
did I do it right?..I will try more..
thanks

Comment: I am working on a game.. which has a "pause" function..
http://99mission.why3s.tw/MOTC/index_mob.html
(show up after few second into game)
above is the transition version... it should work as good as animate version
http://99mission.why3s.tw/MOTC/index_on.html